# How do I understand Pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, pythagorean-triples

1) I understand the formula

$$\frac{BC}{AB}=\frac{BH}{BC},\ \frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{AH}{AC}$$
But I can't understand the formula is obtained

$$BC^2=AB\times BH \ \text{and}\ AC^2=AB\times AH$$

Why if somebody multiplies $AB * BH = AC^2$?

[image: triangle]

2) How is the formula obtained?

$$\frac{\sqrt{AB^2-AC^2}}{AC}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{AC}{AB}\right)^2}$$

I understand first part, but I can't understand second part

Comment: very much thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each equation of the second pair is obtained from an equation in the first pair by "cross-multiplying,"  or equivalently getting rid of the denominators.

For example, start from $\frac{BC}{AB}=\frac{BH}{BC}$. Multiply both sides by $(AB)(BC)$. We get $(BC)(BC)=(AB)(BH)$.

Similarly, from $\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{AH}{AC}$, by multiplying both sides by $(AB)(AC)$ we get $(AC)(AC)=(AB)(AH)$.

To finish, take the two equations $BC^2=(AB)(BH)$ and $AC^2=(AB)(AH)$ and add. We get
$$BC^2+AC^2=AB(BH+AH)=(AB)(AB)=AB^2.$$

**Remark:** As to your question 2, the quoted formula is wrong.  For example, let $AB=5$ and $AC=4$. For these values, the the left-hand side of your expression is equal to $\frac{3}{4}$. The right-hand side is equal to $\frac{3}{5}$.

**Added:** It turns out that OP wants to prove the correct
$$\frac{\sqrt{AB^2-AC^2}}{AB}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{AC}{AB}\right)^2}.\tag{1}$$

Rewrite the left side of (1) as $\sqrt{\frac{AB^2-AC^2}{AB^2}}$. Now divide term by term. We have $\frac{AB^2}{AB^2}=1$  and $\frac{AC^2}{AB^2}=\left(\frac{AC}{AB}\right)^2$, so we obtain the right-hand side of (1)/

The context is that if $\alpha$ is the angle at $A$, then
$\sin\alpha=\frac{BC}{AB}= \frac{\sqrt{AB^2-AC^2}}{AB}$. So on the left-hand side of (1) we have $\sin\alpha$, and on the right-hand side we have $1-\cos^2\alpha$.

Comment: What do you mean by second formula? Specifically, in which line of the answer is it? And nowhere in my answer is there an $AC$ in the denominator. I only did the calculation for one of the equations. But if it will make you more comfortable, I will type the other also.

Comment: sorry for the confusion,I am referring to the second formula in the question, $\frac{\sqrt{AB^2-AC^2}}{AC}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{AC}{AB}\right)^2}$,  I thought your answer helps in understanding the second one as well

Comment: I will write a remark about the second formula.

Comment: I think OP wanted to write $\frac{\sqrt{AB^2-AC^2}}{AB}=...$, but instead of AB he wrote $AC$, if the denominator is $AB$ then LHS=RHS

Comment: Possible. But if that had been OP's intent, the equality would be trivial, and OP would not have asked about it.  So maybe the typo came earlier, in the typing of the problem OP was asked to solve.

Comment: sorry. I got second formula from other book and didn't change the letters. The sense of second formula was obtained second part. I meant $sin$   $a = \frac{\sqrt{BC^2-AC^2}}{BC}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{AC}{BC}\right)^2}=\sqrt{1 - cos^2 a}$ I can't understand how from first part equation is getting second equation

Comment: The equality of the two expressions you now give is trivial, just square both sides. But you probably meant to type something else. So here goes. As to the sine of the angle $\alpha$ at $A$, using the labelling in your picture, it is $\frac{BC}{AB}$. By the Pythagorean Theorem we proved in the answer, we have $BC^2=AB^2-AC^2$, so $BC=\sqrt{AB^2-AC^2}$. Then $\sin\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{AB^2-AC^2}}{AB}$. By easy algebra (bring the bottom $AB$ inside the square root sign as $AB^2$) we get an equation like the one mentioned in the post, except the $AC$ on bottom left is $AB$.

Comment: All before $\sin\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{AB^2-AC^2}}{AB}$ I understand but after that I can't understand. Мy thoughts were so $\sqrt{\frac{AB^2 - AC^2}{AB^2}} = \sqrt {\frac{(AB - AC)(AB + BC)}{AB^2}}$ That's all I can't see how get $\sqrt{1 - (\frac{AC}{BC}^2)}$ Why $1 - (\frac{AC}{BC}^2)$

Comment: It is too hard to type in a comment. I will add to the answer. About $10$ minutes!

Comment: You are welcome.